# Copy only last row

Tags: excel, copy, vba

have a macro that Copies complete columns to another sheet.

Currently though, I need a Macro to only copy the last ROW with data

Example, If i have the following:

Cell A1 = 1, Cell A2 = 2, Cell A3 = 3, Cell A4 = Sum (A1:A3),Cell A5 = Blank

I want the macro to only copy A4. I am doing this for entire columns (A to E) Thanks

Someone already helped me with the below code, which copies all data till the last row, excluding the last row.
I need it to do the opposite, only copy the last row

```
Dim lrow As Long

With wbk4.Sheets("Sheet1")
lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
.Range("A1", "E" & lrow - 1).Copy
wbk2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("XD1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just through quickly checking through the code, would it be:

```
.Range("A1", "E" & lrow - 1).Copy
```

Changed to:

```
.Range("A" & lrow - 1, "E" & lrow).Copy
```

Comment: I tried, getting runtime error. Maybe the syntax is wrong?           "A & lrow - 1"

Comment: oh yes i can see where ive gone wrong! Will update my answer (misplaced quotation mark)

Comment: Excellent. I just  removed the "-1" so it only copies last row :)              .Range("A" & lrow - 1, "E" & lrow).Copy. Thank you very much